# JSR-223 - Where to find ScriptServlet?

Tags: php, servlets, jsr223

I'm confused as to where exactly I should find `com.sun.script.http.ScriptServlet` that I've seen in numerous samples across the web.

Is JSR-223 included in JDK 1.6? I've seen people talk about a reference implementation, but the only working link on Oracle's site doesn't seem to include such a class. My non-local environment also uses OpenJDK, which I doubt would have any Sun implementation of JSR-223 anyway! In this case where can I get it from? I'm not even sure what 'it' is in this scenario :/

I want to be able to use PHP as a view technology, invoked from a Servlet. I gather JSR-223 was designed with this sort fo usage in mind, but I'm struggling to figure out

Edit

One guide in particular (http://acet.rdg.ac.uk/projects/vre/jsr223inst.php) mentions invocation of PHP via JNI, which sounds ideal. If there's something in existence as part of the final spec that'd allow me to do this via Servlet, I'd be a very happy bunny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's available [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/kchung/entry/native_php_in_glassfish_with). Below is an extract of relevance:

> Previously, Ludo and Arun described how to run [PHP 5](http://www.php.net/) on [GlassFish](http://glassfish.java.net/) using [Quercus](http://quercus.caucho.com/), see [here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/ludo/archive/2007/03/100_java_quercu.html) and [here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/arungupta/archive/2007/08/php_in_glassfis.html). However, it is also possible to invoke the native PHP engine on Glassfish, using jsr223 and a PHP bridge. The following steps should work on Sparc Solaris 10.
>
> - Download [script.jar](http://blogs.oracle.com/kchung/resource/script.jar) and drop it into <glassfish>/lib.
> - Download [libphp5-5.0.1-sparc-S2.so](http://download.java.net/maven/2/com/sun/script/php/libphp5/5.0.1/libphp5-5.0.1-sparc-S2.so), save it as libphp5.so and drop it into <glassfish>/lib.
> - Download [phptest.war](http://blogs.oracle.com/kchung/resource/phptest.war) and deploy in Glassfish.
> - Run the PHP on `http://localhost:8080/phptest/hello.php`.

The class you mentioned is contained in the `script.jar` file.

Comment: I was changing the link from the old blogs.sun domain and SO wouldn't let me save the change with a link to localhost.  I'm not sure if my change is exactly what you were going for with that link, so you may want to revisit your last bullet point.

Answer (score 0):

There's [Quercus](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/quercus/), Caucho's Java reimplementation of PHP in Java, quite easy to package as a WAR.  JSR223 is included in Java 6, but the only script engine it's shipped with is Rhino, Mozilla's JavaScript interpreter.  There are a number of JSR-223 compatible script engines available, check out the [repository](http://java.net/projects/scripting/).  Instructions on how to integrate Quercus in eg Glassfish can be found on [Arun Gupta's blog](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/arungupta/archive/2007/08/php_in_glassfis.html).

Comment: Quercus is not a JSR 223 implementation.

Comment: @BalusC it's listed as JSR223 compliant in numerous places, so I never really saw the usefulness of verifying that clam :-).  And IMO it remains a much cleaner and more versatile way to run php from a servlet environment than the jni way...

Comment: I tried Quercus once before but it doesn't show the same behaviour as PHP proper - for instance it has some differences with defining classes that prevent the Kohana PHP framework from working.